# Ubuntu 10.10 notification system area , many icons disappeared like network manager

Tags: ubuntu, power-management, networkmanager, icons, bluetooth

When I restarted the computer I found no network icon. I tried to access internet but no connection was found. I also didn't have the Bluetooth, sound, battery, and power icon. Its really crazy that I have to use these commands to display them:

---

```
bluetooth-applet
nm-applet --sm-disable
gnome-power-manager
```

---

Every time I start the system I face this trouble! How can I fix it? Is there anyway to restore previous configuration?

the history log

```
Start-Date: 2011-03-16  11:35:58
Install: hijra-applet:amd64 (0.1.18-3), python-hijra:amd64 (0.1.18-3, automatic), python-eggtrayicon:amd64 (2.25.3-5ubuntu2, automatic)
End-Date: 2011-03-16  11:36:15

Start-Date: 2011-03-16  19:12:49
Upgrade: libkrb5-3:amd64 (1.8.1+dfsg-5ubuntu0.4, 1.8.1+dfsg-5ubuntu0.6), libk5crypto3:amd64 (1.8.1+dfsg-5ubuntu0.4, 1.8.1+dfsg-5ubuntu0.6), chromium-browser:amd64 (10.0.648.127~r76697-0ubuntu0.10.10.1, 10.0.648.133~r77742-0ubuntu0.10.10.1), chromium-browser-l10n:amd64 (10.0.648.127~r76697-0ubuntu0.10.10.1, 10.0.648.133~r77742-0ubuntu0.10.10.1), chromium-codecs-ffmpeg:amd64 (10.0.648.127~r76697-0ubuntu0.10.10.1, 10.0.648.133~r77742-0ubuntu0.10.10.1), libkrb5support0:amd64 (1.8.1+dfsg-5ubuntu0.4, 1.8.1+dfsg-5ubuntu0.6), libtiff4:amd64 (3.9.4-2ubuntu0.1, 3.9.4-2ubuntu0.2), chromium-browser-inspector:amd64 (10.0.648.127~r76697-0ubuntu0.10.10.1, 10.0.648.133~r77742-0ubuntu0.10.10.1), libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 (1.8.1+dfsg-5ubuntu0.4, 1.8.1+dfsg-5ubuntu0.6)
End-Date: 2011-03-16  19:13:11

Start-Date: 2011-03-16  20:52:52
Install: gpredict:amd64 (1.1-7)
End-Date: 2011-03-16  20:53:03

Start-Date: 2011-03-16  20:55:55
Install: libwxbase2.6-0:amd64 (2.6.3.2.2-5ubuntu1, automatic), tipptrainer-data-de:amd64 (0.6.0-17, automatic), libwxgtk2.6-0:amd64 (2.6.3.2.2-5ubuntu1, automatic), tipptrainer:amd64 (0.6.0-17), wx2.6-i18n:amd64 (2.6.3.2.2-5ubuntu1, automatic)
End-Date: 2011-03-16  20:56:02

Start-Date: 2011-03-16  21:28:07
Remove: libwxbase2.6-0:amd64 (2.6.3.2.2-5ubuntu1), tipptrainer-data-de:amd64 (0.6.0-17), libwxgtk2.6-0:amd64 (2.6.3.2.2-5ubuntu1), tipptrainer:amd64 (0.6.0-17), wx2.6-i18n:amd64 (2.6.3.2.2-5ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2011-03-16  21:28:16

Start-Date: 2011-03-16  21:28:22
Install: libwxbase2.6-0:amd64 (2.6.3.2.2-5ubuntu1, automatic), tipptrainer-data-de:amd64 (0.6.0-17, automatic), libwxgtk2.6-0:amd64 (2.6.3.2.2-5ubuntu1, automatic), tipptrainer:amd64 (0.6.0-17), wx2.6-i18n:amd64 (2.6.3.2.2-5ubuntu1, automatic)
End-Date: 2011-03-16  21:28:27

Start-Date: 2011-03-16  21:28:53
Remove: libwxbase2.6-0:amd64 (2.6.3.2.2-5ubuntu1), tipptrainer-data-de:amd64 (0.6.0-17), libwxgtk2.6-0:amd64 (2.6.3.2.2-5ubuntu1), tipptrainer:amd64 (0.6.0-17), wx2.6-i18n:amd64 (2.6.3.2.2-5ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2011-03-16  21:28:56

Start-Date: 2011-03-16  21:31:49
Install: klavaro:amd64 (1.5.0-1build1), libgtkdatabox-0.9.1-1:amd64 (0.9.1.1-3.1, automatic)
End-Date: 2011-03-16  21:31:57
```

Another problem that I didn't notice is that there is a problem with the graphics card also the visual effects can't be applied as in these photos[image: the drivers aren't installed][image: the effect can't be applied]
it was working before.

---

another problem appeared I can't install any software from software center i click the install but nothing happens i tried many programs but the same result!! the internet connection is ok!!
I think it is virus but  heard that Linux is so powerful in security.
I haven't seen a thing like this since windows 98 and XP first edition when viruses change desktop background and disable some menu items

Comment: Maybe this isn't an issue, but [looking at Ubuntu repos](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=chromium&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all), your version of Chromium is outdated. Have you enable the security repositories too, as well as maverick-updates? Enable them, update, and upgrade again.

Comment: the system update is enabled the chrome I installed it from Ubuntu software center ?!!how to enable the security repositories??

Comment: Go to Edit menu of software-center and click of Software sources, and go to Updates tab. In future, just ask a separate question.

Comment: Regarding the inability to install from software-center: After enabling the security/updates from your APT sources, please use the terminal to upgrade the system, to see if it works: `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Another thing is you might wanna log into chat so we can troubleshoot your problem easier.

Comment: You should open 3 different questions, because they don't seem to be related, so it is easier to work on each question stringently, to upvote `the` right/best answer and accept it, to tag them well, to find matching answers, if somebody has similar problems. You may provide links between them, if you think they are useful.

Answer (score 1):

Go **System** -> **Preferences** -> **Startup Applications**, and add those three commands manually.

[image]

Maybe you got them removed from there (or disabled) by mistake.

Comment: they are already added ! I've got these commands from it!! but it don't work . it was working but i updated the system and restarted it then the problem came

Comment: @Ahmedsafan: You sure they are not disabled?

Comment: @Ahmedsafan: Have a look at /var/log/apt/history.log to check what the latest stuff you've installed is. Paste the last few entries (in the hope that it will include your latest updates). I'm interesting specifically in **`gnome-session`** which is the one that that GUI belongs to.

Comment: i added the last activities on log since yesterday [the day of the disaster]